# "gcc" command refers to "perl"

Tags: perl, gcc, path, symbian

Platform: Windows 7 64 bit

Hi all,

I want to compile with gcc. So I have added the path to the gcc binary to the PATH environment variables. Whenever I type gcc in the command prompt, I wish to see something like "no input file specified" (from gcc itself). But instead I get the message "perl is not recognzied".

To cut short, when I type gcc in the command prompt it refers to perl for some reason. I have check all environment variables, and there is nothing that points to perl...

I have rebooted for several times already, without success.

It is not much of a problem to use the full path to gcc when I want to compile just a single file. But when I use make it does not work. Because make uses the gcc command again. Which then refers to "perl".

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should paste the error message

Comment: Is this Unix? What is the output of `which gcc` and `type gcc` from your command-line?

Answer (score 2):

How odd.

Try:

```
set CC=x:\path\to\gcc
make ...
```

(See http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Implicit-Variables.html.)

Comment: Still the same. I also found out that the make command also refers to perl.... I had carbide, nokia symbian SDK installed (which need perl to compile Symbian C++ code), but I uninstalled them all, rebooting, nothing... still refering to perl.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, now I read this comment, this is really a Symbian development environment issue. I'd tag it as such, and you might get more focused help

Answer (score 2):

Don't use make on Windows. Use dmake -- available at: http://search.cpan.org/dist/dmake/

make on MinGW(32|64) is somewhat broken at the best of times. Windows Perl's are usually built with dmake (or nmake if you are using Visual C++).

Comment: @sidyll easier said than done if your clients require it. Sometimes it's that or port the whole lot to Visual Basic

Comment: Yes, I see. I just mean that, if you use Windows, it's easier to switch completely than trying to port every Unix tool (Perl, make, ...). But I understand, was just kidding in the last comment.